# JButton call clicked button's method

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a custom JButton

```
public class MoreButton extends JButton{

    private String modCode;

    public MoreButton(ButtonListener listen, String code){
        this.setText("More");
        this.addActionListener(listen);

        modCode = code;
    }

    public String getCode(){
        return modCode;
    }
}
```

Now whenever I click it I want to call the `getCode()` method.
I'm wondering if something like

```
event.getSource().getCode();
```

is possible?

Comment: I think you are looking for JButton.setAction(Action);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this *should* work, assuming you have an ActionListener on the button (Not tested).

```
if(event.getSource() instanceof MoreButton){
    String code = ((MoreButton)event.getSource()).getCode();
    //do something
}
```